# DynamicModule's Deinitialization & CDFDeploy

Tags: bugs, export, cdf-format

**Bug introduced in V10.1 or earlier and persisting through V11.3**

> [CASE:3362265]

---

This evaluates fine for me:

```
CDFDeploy["test.cdf"
, DynamicModule[{}, Dynamic["Hello World"], Deinitialization :> 1]
]
```

But this results in a never ending evaluation that can not be aborted and requires you to quit Mathematica (not just the kernel)

```
CDFDeploy["test.cdf"
, DynamicModule[{}, Dynamic[{"Hello World"}], Deinitialization :> 1]
]
```

In practice any non trivial `DynamicModule` with `Deinitialization` can not be deployed as CDF...

Can you reproduce this? What can we do about this?

I have tried this in Mathematica 10.1 and 10.2 for Windows.

Comment: I am on MMA 10.2 (Win7). I can confirm that the first expression works fine, while the second one runs forever. The kernel reports "INTERNAL SELF-TEST ERROR: Kernels|c|6973" in the message window upon execution. **This has to do with the `Deinitialization` option** though, and not with the curly braces: without `Deinitialization`, either form works fine, with or without the braces. In the aftermath, quitting the kernel seems sufficient to recover on my system; the front end seems unaffected thereafter. This sure looks like a bug.

Comment: Update from WRI: "[...] The developer will try to fix the issue but there's no timeframe on when it'll be resolved unfortunately. [...]"

Answer (score 3):

Since it is already 3 years and counting it would be nice to have a workaround.

Don't have a perfect one but you can `Export` as .cdf which will be fine as long as you don't need `CDFDeploy's` options: `"Target"/Deployed` which are not respected by `Export[..., "CDF", ...]`:

```
Export[
  "test.cdf"
, DynamicModule[{}, Dynamic[{"Hello World"}], Deinitialization :> 1]
, "CDF"
]
```

Another workaround is to use wrap your `DynamicModule` with a notebook with:

```
NotebookEventActions :> {"WindowClose" :> deinitialization}
```

The downside is it will not have access to `DynamicModule's` variables (or it will require case specific tweaks). Additionaly `"WindowClose"` probably is not as general as `Deinitialization`. But I didn't test this method too much.